# How to handle a shared lib calling exit() and unexpectedly destroying global objects?

Tags: linux, multithreading, shared-libraries, glibc

An application uses librpm.so, which handles some errors by calling `exit()`, for example [when it receives a SIGPIPE](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/api/4.4.2.2/rpmdb_8c-source.html#L00747). This results in glibc destroying local static objects while other threads are accessing them, resulting in a crash.

Is there a way for the application to clean up (uninitialize modules that use threads) before glibc starts destroying static instances ? These modules are started from compiled shared libraries.

Comment: Don't use libraries which break out of their abstraction and end your process.  Such a "library" is not fit to be a library, only a child process.

Comment: @BenVoigt The entire C++ standard library is heavily based on the standard C library which indeed breaks a ton of abstractions. In fact, the C++ standard library is just a thin wrapper most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can be proactive a catch SIGPIPE before the library takes it.

Example: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Comment: Sounds good if everything else fails, but [librpm replaces signal handlers with its own functions](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/api/4.4.2.2/rpmsq_8c-source.html#L00378). And using `signalfd` doesn't help since a `read()` from the fd will return after the librpm handler is called.

Comment: @patraulea `librpm` appears to be utter shiite egested from the south end of a northbound bull.  `ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&sq->mutex);` **in a signal handler**?!?!?!  Bit-bucket that garbage.

Comment: That is ridiculous. A library cannot set global signal handlers on behalf of the whole application.

Comment: @SomethingSomething IMO it can - if it chains its signal handler(s) in nicely allowing other signal handlers to work too, and **clearly** documents it.  And then doesn't rely on the handlers for core functionality but only "nice to have" bonus features.

Comment: I misrepresented librpm above, the sources were from an old version from RHEL 6 or 7, while in recent versions they save and restore the old signal handlers. So it's only an issue for applications that run on older distributions. It looks like older versions were simply not meant to be embedded in other binaries than rpm, yum, etc.